# Purge content in Varnish when CTRL+F5 or CTRL+R is pressed

Tags: cache, varnish

I would like to setup Varnish to purge content in cache and get it directly from backend when CTRL+R or CTLR+F5 is pressed.

I use these rules but this only gets content from backend when CTRL+F5 is pressed. When I press F5 only I get data from cache.

```
acl CTRLF5 {
   "127.0.0.1";
}

sub vcl_hit {

  if (client.ip ~ CTRLF5) {
    if (req.http.pragma ~ "no-cache" || req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache")
    {
      set obj.ttl = 0s;
      return(pass);
    }
    else { return(deliver); }
  }
  else { return(deliver); }
}
```

Comment: Which browser do you use for testing ? Could you post the request headers sent when you F5 a page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be realised with next statements:

varnish 2.1.x

```
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache"){
    purge_url(req.url);
    }
```

varnish 3.x

```
    if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache"){
    ban(req.url);
    }
```

Comment: Firefox 10.1 when pressing F5, but I will try your rules :) HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Etag: "2252232387"
Last-Modified: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 18:00:59 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 12 Feb 2012 18:11:31 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: HIT
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: private

Comment: It still doesn't work. Pressing F5 or CTLR+R gets content from cache. CTLR+F5 gets content from disk.

Comment: There is a nice config, but it do not work with Varnish 3.0: http://pastebin.com/HGbYKz8a

Comment: Got it: http://pastebin.com/haQgdPYH